# ffmpeg to get screenshot

Tags: java, ubuntu, screenshot

I have a collections of videos, and I would like to get a screenshot from every on of them, and save them all in a folder.
I was told about ffmpeg, a Linux command. But the only extension I get is mpg, instead of .jpeg or .png.

Anybody could tell me if it is possible to write something similar to:

> ffmpeg -i
>   videoscambiados/"+filename+".flv
>   img/"+filename+".png

instead of this?

> ffmpeg -i
>   videoscambiados/"+filename+".flv
>   img/"+filename+".mpg

This piece of code is got from a java program I made, and filename, of course, is the name of every videos I have in /videoscambiados and I would like to save the images in /img

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ffmpeg -i videoscambiados/" +filename+
>   ".flv -r 1 -ss 00:00:10 -t 1 -s
>   146x110 img/" +filename+ ".jpg