# Retrieve a thumbnail of any video in an iFrame?

Tags: php, iframe, video-thumbnails

I have various video hosts that I like to use on my website. I am trying to code a way to retrieve their video thumbnails.

Most of these video hosts actually have a frame of the video on display before the video starts to play. If it's possible to even get that frame as the thumbnail, that would be great.  Most if not all of these video hosts use iframes for embedding.

I am looking for a fairly generic way of retrieving thumbnails for all video hosts that display some type of frame from the video once the video is embedded. If that frame can somehow be retrieved and then turned into an image that can be used that would be amazing. However, I am not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to have the actual binary file data. If you have that access, install ffmpeg-php on your server and use this question for further direction: [ffmpeg to get screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068424/ffmpeg-to-get-screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the site.

For example, if you have a youtube video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC2FKbyC28k

then its thumbnail is at
http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/AC2FKbyC28k/mqdefault.jpg

I found this out by right clicking the image thumbnail, opening it in a tab and inspecting the url, so I'm sure you can do this exhaustively for every site ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/), which is supported by most popular video hosting sites (Youtube, Vimeo, ...). There are several [PHP oEmbed libraries](https://packagist.org/search/?q=oembed), which come preconfigured with oEmbed endpoints.

What oEmbed allows you to do is to make a request to the provider (Youtube for example) with the video URL. It will return a JSON response with information about the video. Both Youtube and Vimeo return a `thumbnail_url` element in the JSON.